# Keycloak authorization services don't deny scopes in resource

Tags: keycloak

I am testing Keycloak authorization services in the admin console and I'm unable to understand why in the next example keycloak is authorizing a user (tested in the `evaluate` tab). this is my setup :

- Created a realm `test`
- Created a client `democlient` with `Authorization Enabled` on
- Create the realm role `Admin`
- Create the user `adminuser` and assign it to the `Admin` role

---

In the `Authorization` tab withing the client `democlient`:

- In `Settings` -> `Policy Enforcement Mode` is set to `Enforcing`
- Create 2 scopes: `list` and `save`
- Create a resource `Resource A` with the 2 previous scopes
- In `Policies` tab, create a new `Role policy` called **Only admins** where (of course) i only permit admins:
  [image: creation of role policy]
- In `Permissions` tab, created a `Scoped-based` permission called **permit only admins Resource A, list Scope**:
  [image: Creation of permission where only an admin can access the Resource A and Scope list]

And that's it. now i check in the `evaluate` tab this policy using the adminuser, role Admin, Resource A, Scope List:

[image: Keycloak Authorizing the rule]

success! everything is fine in the world!... except **No**. 
checking again the policy with the adminuser, role Admin, Resource A, **Scope save** (a scope where I did not define any permission) Keycloak is again Authorizing this rule :/

i assumed that `policy enforcement mode` set to `Enforcing` will deny the access to scope save, from the documentation of keycloak:

> The policy enforcement mode dictates how policies are enforced when evaluating authorization requests. 'Enforcing' means requests are denied by default even when there is no policy associated with a given resource. 'Permissive' means requests are allowed even when there is no policy associated with a given resource. 'Disabled' completely disables the evaluation of policies and allows access to any resource.

so... what i am doing wrong? how can i make that keycloak deny the access to the `save scope`? (obviously i can make a permission where i explicitly deny this scope. but i want that the default is deny as the documentation says)
Any ideas will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I tried to recreate your situation. And yes I get a permission in both cases. But in both cases the payload of the permission says "Granted Scopes: list". I don't know why Keycloak wouldn't deny the access, but it says resource access is fine with list scope. Have you tried getting a permission from the token endpoint via HTTP? It should answer with a json in which you can find the permission.

Comment: I didn't really work with realm roles yet. In my case I used the authorization code grant from OAuth2. I had a user (human with username and password) and a client (eg an app) and those tried to access another client (resource server). The user had client roles from the first client. The resource server had policies, which would consider the client roles of the app.

Comment: @JWo yes, i tried the token endpoint, but the answer is the same, the client is authorized anyway :( off course if a explicitly deny a scope it works, but i don't want to manually deny every scope for every role that i don't want. can you please expand how did you use client roles and policies? thanks

Comment: @Christian Same situation for us, did you find a solution? I've just written to the Keycloak mailing list...

Comment: Same here do you have the link of the mailing list @Reste85 ?

Comment: They talk about this in this mailing list https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-February/017174.html. Would be interesting to find the corresponding jira thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the Jira issue that reference this problem It's clearly a bug:

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-9483

There is a patch that will come with the Keycloak version 9.0

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12438.

So we just need to wait for this release

Comment: yes, testing right now with keycloak 9.0.0 everything is working as expected, so @Reste85 this is the solution